# Why was my question closed? Not all "shopping" questions are the same

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked [my very first Mechanics SO question today](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/73610/suzuki-aerio-06-5-door-wagon-roof-rack-for-factory-mounting-points) ...and it was closed very quickly. It is frustrating to see that the same bad habits that are being fought by the StackOverflow since last year are not being addressed on the smaller SE sites.

The closing reason mentions a "shopping question":

> Questions seeking price/shopping assistance are off-topic because [they tend to become obsolete quickly](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Well actually™, not all "shopping" questions are the same. Even the blog post referred to in the closing reason says so.

[image]

I suspect the closer(s) didn't bother to read my question carefully, because the question I posted:

- includes the specific car make, model, kind, and year.
- includes the intended application/use of the product (satisfies the `describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve` suggestion).
- includes the constraints to the product I'm looking for (namely, the mounting type, and the sturdiness for the intended use).
- includes the request to any things I should be careful about when buying a product.
- **DOES NOT include** an ask for a recommendation of a particular product or producer.
- will have a long-lasting valid answer (as opposed to many other shopping questions) -- see why below.

I did my homework spending several days learning about the subject through Google, YouTube, and various seller sites. Still have no clear picture of what and how to search for. Even the likely to be valid products for Suzuki Liana are discontinued, so the answer to my question has high chances of staying valid for a long time.

Closing the question with a blanket response is either negligence or hostility. Especially, if we're looking at a question from a new member. Is this really what Mechanics.SO is alike? I propose reconsidering my questions's validity and re-opening it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, your question appears to be open and has an [answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/73626/57). Do you still feel that there is a meta question that needs to be addressed?

As an aside, our [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) is generally pretty active. It’s a great place to have a discussion about things like “hey, what’s up with my question?” It’s also a good place for straight up shopping tips (you’ll hear a lot about sales at Harbor Freight!)

Comment: I haven't the question reopened until now. Thank you for pointing out! I appreciate the reference to the chatroom as well.

Answer (score 0):

While I can appreciate the zeal for your own question, what you've stated in your Meta question does not in the least sway me to believe your question is anything other than a shopping question. You've done nothing more than restated you are "looking for a product", which to me is a shopping question. If you can reword your question to fit within the guidelines, I'll gladly reopen it.

On a separate note ... I'm not sure how or why they do things on other SO stacks, however, writing statements on here trying to bully your way to getting a question reopened is doing exactly what you are suggesting is happening on other sites and accusing Mech of doing. I don't frequent a lot of other stacks, so I don't know how they do things. I am familiar enough with SO to know it's not somewhere I want to ask a lot of questions. They are quite persnickety, to say the least. No, we don't behave like that here. Nor do we accept bullying behavior, either. Please remember, the new Code of Conduct doesn't like bullying, no matter how it is being applied.

Again, take a look at your question. Reword it to fit within the guidelines. This can be done through taking pertinent parts out. Leave the word "product" out of it. A product available today may not be available tomorrow. Please ... just have a look and see what you can do with it.

Comment: "No, we don't behave like that here. Nor do we accept bullying behavior, either." I tend to agree with many other SE users rather than with your statement. Saying I'm trying to "bully my way" instead of pointing out the specific issues with the original question is exactly what qualifies as bullying. That is precisely one of the SE's target areas of improvement nowadays.

Comment: "Leave the word "product" out of it." Well, my initial question only mentions word product once and in the sentence that stresses that I am not asking for a particular item recommendation. I have no idea what edits to the question would make it valid in your eyes.

Comment: In this meta question I am also referring to the blog post which explains why I believe my question isn't a yet-another-shopping-question. How much of burden of proof should I bear?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko - I'm more than happy to allow the populace to reopen your question, if they feel I was wrong. You are new to this Stack, I get it. We aren't like any other Stack on the Exchange, I can guarantee you this. Again, your demeanor is not helping you. Trying to bully an elected Mod is definitely not the way to go to accomplish anything. I've given you two ways forward. Please just choose one and go with it.

Comment: You didn't give me a direction of the question change you expect to see. Nor replied to the points I made about the guiding blog post. I saw everything I needed to see looks like. "Trying to bully an elected Mod..." phrase *is* the bullying. Would be smarter for me to leave the paper tiger alone. Cheers!